# Mocking Camel endpoints with spring-configured camelContext

Tags: java, spring, junit, integration-testing, apache-camel

I'm trying to figure out the "correct" way of mocking out an Endpoint in an integration test that uses spring test support.

The code is working, but I'm wondering if this is the correct way of doing it. I've looked at the camel-test Test Kit and it's [adviceWith](http://camel.apache.org/advicewith.html), but that is not useful when spring is responsible for loading the camelContex in the test, right?

This is what I have:

**The service:**

```
@Service
public class FtpOutboundFileStrategy implements OutboundFileExportStrategy {
    private final String FTP_PATTERN= "{0}://{1}@{2}";
    private final ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public FtpOutboundPriceFileStrategy(ProducerTemplate producerTemplate) {
        this.producerTemplate = producerTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public void doExport(OutboundFile file, ExportProperties exportProperties) {
        this.producerTemplate.sendBodyAndHeader(createFtpUri(exportProperties),
                file.getFileContent(), Exchange.FILE_NAME, file.getFileName());
    }
}
```

**The integration test:**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:testDB.xml", "classpath:applicationContext.xml"})
public class FtpOutboundFileStrategyIT {

    @EndpointInject(uri = "mock:ftp")
    protected MockEndpoint fakeEndpoint;

    @Autowired
    FtpOutboundFileStrategy ftpOutboundPriceFileStrategy;

    @Autowired
    protected CamelContext camelContext;

    @DirtiesContext
    @Test
    public void directsToFtpEndpoint() throws Exception {
        camelContext.addEndpoint("ftp://foo@localhost", fakeEndpoint);

        fakeEndpoint.expectedBodyReceived().equals("This is the file");
        ftpOutboundPriceFileStrategy.doExport(new OutboundFile("This is the file"),
                new ExportProperties("foo", "localhost"));
        fakeEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
    }
}
```

Now, this works, but I'm wondering if this is sort of a hack:

```
camelContext.addEndpoint("ftp://foo@localhost", fakeEndpoint);
```

I read somewhere that using `@EndpointInject(uri = "mock:ftp")` would create a mocked endpoint with higher present that the default FtpEndpoint, but if I leave this out the test fails because it's using the default.

Another strange thing is that if i use **"ftp*"** instead of **"ftp://foo@localhost"** in the mocks uri the test fails as well, which has led me to believe that this is not the correct way of doing it.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think David Valeri is working on improving camel-test-spring to be able to do more Camel stuff with the pure Spring Test Kit. There is a JIRA ticket, so keep an eye out for improvements in the future.

At first though you can use Spring property placeholders, to replace the endpoint uris, so when running the tests, you can substitute the actual ftp endpoints, with a mock endpoint etc.

See this FAQ about Spring XML limitations
http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-use-spring-property-placeholder-with-camel-xml.html

Chapter 6 in the Camel in Action book, also covers how to testing with Spring property placeholders, and have a test.properties and production.properties file that contains the actual endpoint uris.

Alternative in you test method, you can use the Camel advice-with API to alter the route and whatnot before running the test. See details here: http://camel.apache.org/advicewith.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! In this specific case I want the endpoint uri to be dynamic (decided by the ExportProperties), so I guess that means I'm going to have to manually add the endpoint mock for now? Also I'm not using any routes (I think), so that means the adwiceWith api is useless right? Or does a direct invocation of ProducerTemplate create a dynamic route?

Comment: No advice-with applies for routes only. ProducerTemplate will lookup endpoints from the registry directly. You can use a custom EndpointStrategy and register it using addRegisterEndpointCallback to the CamelContext, then you can influence under which uri endpoints is being registered. However its a bit do it yourself, and also how Camel does some of its intercept send to endpoints and send to mocks as well.

Comment: Thanks again! Last question :) Why can't I manually "replace" the FtpEndpoint like so: `camelContext.addEndpoint("ftp", fakeEndpoint);`?   I thought the protocol decided which implementation of the endpoint it was dispatched to? If so it shouldn't really matter what the host is? In order to get it to work I have to explicitly replace the endpoint with at full uri like: `camelContext.addEndpoint("ftp://foo@localhost", fakeEndpoint);`.

Comment: You would need to remove the old endpoints in case they are already in use, there is API on CamelContext to remove endpoints, it support wildcards. eg if a producer template already have looked up the real ftp endpoint, and then you later replace that, then the producer will still use the real endpoint. eg its about chicken-egg, which comes first.

Comment: btw this is the JIRA ticket about Davids work: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-4987

Comment: Btw we are adding a new stub component in Camel 2.10: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CAMEL/Stub

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [a small article](http://labs.bsb.com/2011/06/unit-test-production-route-in-apache-camel-using-mock-endpoints/) on using the **mockAllEndpoints** new feature of Camel (> 2.7).
you can also find the official documentation [here](http://camel.apache.org/mock.html#Mock-MockingexistingendpointswithXMLDSL).

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this applies since I'm not defining any routes, instead I use the producer template directly?

Answer (score 0):

Try extending the test class with

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyConfigurationClass.class)
//this could be an xml file as well with locations attribute
public class CamelRoutesTest extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests{
```

I had similar issue. This fixed camelContext and applicationContext related problem